# How to create read-only entity in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, orm

My app is purely read-only so I don't want to generate all the update & delete code, and I don't want to pull in all fields from all tables.  Some of these fields are not nullable so I am getting errors from EF here becasue there is no default value to save.

In my previous ORM (Wilson) you could just flag an entity as read-only in the XML. I've seen a few posts showing convoluted solutions to this. Am I missing something? Why isn't this straight forward?

I see that the RIA services wizard has a check box for this for each entity...

Comment: You need to be more precise about the errors you see and in what circumstances you see them. There's not a "read-only" feature, but your app should still work, anyway.

Comment: After removing some columns (that are non-null in the database) from the entity in the designer I get the error: "Column xyz in table ABC must be mapped: It has no default value and is not nullable." Which makes sense sort of, but I want to ignore that column completely and not have EF build update code at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a non-nullable field in your SSDL which isn't in your CSDL.

You can manually remove the column from SSDL and the EF will be happy. **But** the designer will re-add the column when you update the model. So you can either remove it again or update your model from a variant of the DB which doesn't have that column.

Comment: That's what I suspected. But why? What was the difficulty in allowing a read-only attribute, or in removing the column from the SSDL if I remove it from the EDMX?

Comment: You can't have a read-only, non-nullable attribute on a read-write type, and the EF doesn't have a "read-only type" feature, AFAIK. Removing a column from SSDL isn't "hard," but the designer chooses not to do it because in the GUI designer's world, the SSDL is *always* generated (and, frequently, re-generated), not manually maintained.

Comment: OK, I can accept to remove the column from SSDL (and keep removing it) but what about all the crud code generated - it's just annoying knowing that it's there even when not required. Wonder what the problem with EF not having a read-only type attribute is...